# MongoDB: Zip File Error after download from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mean-stack

I'm trying to attach zip file to an object and request zip file when the object is called from the client, I was able to upload the zip file like this

```
const upload = multer({
    fileFilter(req, file, cb){
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(html|zip)$/)) {
            return cb(new Error("Please upload a .html or .zip file"))
        }
        cb(undefined, true)
    }
})

router.post('/map/:id/file/upload/zip', auth, upload.single('zip'), async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const map = await Map.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        if (!map) {
            return res.status(400).send({"message":"Map is not found in database"})
        }
        map.zipBuffer = req.file.buffer
        map.save()
        res.status(201).send(map)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})
```

it saved successfully, but whenever I download I get

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

This is my code block for pulling the zip file

```
router.get('/map/:id/file/upload/zip', async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const map = await Map.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        if (!map) {
            return res.status(400).send({"message":"No map found"})
        }
        const html = map.htmlBuffer
        res.set("Content-Type","application/x-zip-compressed")
        res.send(html)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})
```

I need help on how to properly upload a zipped file and get it back without damaging the file.

Comment: You need to read the buffer I'm guessing instead of trying to store the buffer object. Depending on the size of the file you may also need to use GridFS instead.

Comment: When u say “Read the buffer”, what does that mean?

Comment: The size of the zipped file is less than 50kb

Comment: You are probably assigning the string "object" to your field rather than the contents of the uploaded field.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=nodejs+read+buffer&ia=web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny that the answer to your question is already looking at you on the face.

There are some inconsistencies with the codes below:

```
const html = map.htmlBuffer
res.set("Content-Type","application/x-zip-compressed")
res.send(html)
```

Here you are sending back the file as HTML buffer while you are expecting a zip format.

Refactor the codes above with the right format and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to suggest a more generic approach to [destiny-ajakaiye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301975/13741871), you can write

```
res.set("Content-Type", map.contentType)
```